# Filter dataframe by key in a list of dictionaries in pyspark

Tags: dictionary, pyspark

In pyspark, how do I to filter a dataframe that has a column that is a list of dictionaries, based on a specific dictionary key value?

```
+------------------------------------+---------------+
|foo_dic_list                        |text           |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
|[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]       |teacher        |
|[{'2': [5,2,3] }]                   |student        |
|[{'4': [2,2,2]}]                    |gamer          |
|[{'3': [3,3,3]}]                    |robot          | 
+------------------------------------+---------------+
```

I want to select rows like below, which contains "4" in keys of foo_dic_list column.

```
+------------------------------------+---------------+
|foo_dic_list                        |text           |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
|[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]       |teacher        |
|[{'4': [2,2,2]}]                    |gamer          |
+------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: what is the data type of that column?

Comment: oh good question. the datatype is string.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but we can use an UDF to get the list of keys and then use `array_contains()` on that to filter. *The below only works if there's just one dictionary within the array.*

```
# based on your comment the column is of string data type
data_ls = [
    ('''[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]''', 'teacher'),
    ('''[{'2': [5,2,3] }]''', 'student'),
    ('''[{'4': [2,2,2]}]''', 'gamer')
]

data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data_ls).toDF(['foo_dic_list', 'text'])

# +-----------------------------+-------+
# |foo_dic_list                 |text   |
# +-----------------------------+-------+
# |[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]|teacher|
# |[{'2': [5,2,3] }]            |student|
# |[{'4': [2,2,2]}]             |gamer  |
# +-----------------------------+-------+

# root
#  |-- foo_dic_list: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

Create a function to parse it as json string resulting in a list of dictionary. Then fetch the dictionary and use it to fetch list of keys using `dict.keys()`.

```
def getDictKeys(json_str):
    import json

    json_dict = json.loads(json_str.replace("\'", '\"'))[0]
    json_dict_keys = list(json_dict.keys())

    return json_dict_keys

getDictKeys_udf = func.udf(getDictKeys, ArrayType(StringType()))

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('keys_arr', getDictKeys_udf(func.col('foo_dic_list'))). \
    filter(func.array_contains('keys_arr', '4')). \
    select('foo_dic_list', 'text'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----------------------------+-------+
# |foo_dic_list                 |text   |
# +-----------------------------+-------+
# |[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]|teacher|
# |[{'4': [2,2,2]}]             |gamer  |
# +-----------------------------+-------+
```

---

The `keys_arr` field looks like the following

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('keys_arr', getDictKeys_udf(func.col('foo_dic_list'))). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----------------------------+-------+--------+
# |foo_dic_list                 |text   |keys_arr|
# +-----------------------------+-------+--------+
# |[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]|teacher|[1, 4]  |
# |[{'2': [5,2,3] }]            |student|[2]     |
# |[{'4': [2,2,2]}]             |gamer  |[4]     |
# +-----------------------------+-------+--------+

# root
#  |-- foo_dic_list: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- text: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- keys_arr: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

---

The `like()` operator also kinda worked with my sample.

```
data_sdf. \
    filter(func.col('foo_dic_list').like("%'4':%")). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-----------------------------+-------+
# |foo_dic_list                 |text   |
# +-----------------------------+-------+
# |[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]|teacher|
# |[{'4': [2,2,2]}]             |gamer  |
# +-----------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

choose the easy way: using `locate` like this.  And then filter `location > 0`

```
d1 = [
    ("[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]", "teacher"),
    ("[{'2': [5,2,3] }]",             "student"),
    ("[{'4': [2,2,2]}]",              "gamer"),
    ("[{'3': [3,3,3]}]",              "robot"),
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['foo_dic_list', 'text'])
df1.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- foo_dic_list: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- text: string (nullable = true)
df1.withColumn('location', locate("\'4\':", col('foo_dic_list'))).show(10, False)
# +-----------------------------+-------+--------+
# |foo_dic_list                 |text   |location|
# +-----------------------------+-------+--------+
# |[{'1': [1,2,3],'4': [2,3,4]}]|teacher|16      |
# |[{'2': [5,2,3] }]            |student|0       |
# |[{'4': [2,2,2]}]             |gamer  |3       |
# |[{'3': [3,3,3]}]             |robot  |0       |
# +-----------------------------+-------+--------+
```